# Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong in this peice of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey every I am getting an error in this following piece of code, I am using HTML & JAVASCRIPT.

Can any help me fix this out?

I am getting Undefined error.

Here is the code.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var x;

  function setvar() {
   
   var x = "Hello World";

  }

  function alt() {

   alert(x);

  }
 </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body onload="setvar();">
 <button onclick="alt();">Do it!!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Or can you provide a snippet that reproduces the error?

Comment: i am getting undefined error

Comment: `function setvar() {
x = "Hello World";
}`

Comment: The first var x is a global variable, the second is a scoped variable that only works in your function. But sinds the global variable x is already there, your scoped variable x (with the same name) can not be working together. You should keep the global var en make the second (scoped) var like this: x = "hello world"; EDIT: check @EvertvdH. his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a scoping issue. if you use `var` inside a `function`, that variable will only exist in the scope of that function.

So what you could do is this:

```
var x;

function setVar() {
    x = 'Hello World';
}

function alt() {
    alert(x);
}
```

By removing `var` in the setVar function, you're updating the `var` that is created outside the function.

Hope that makes sense.